# Memory leak in Objective-c UIImage to Greyscale Bitmap conversion function

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, cgimage

I am trying to solve a memory leak problem with an iOS app and I have narrowed it down to this function that converts a UIImage to a greyscale bitmap.  The code works fine but uses up about 500kb per run.

I have a feeling its caused by the CGImageRef and CGDataRef not being released, but if I release either of them at the end of the function with CGImageRelease(sourceImage) or CGDataRelease(theData) then the returned image grayBitmapImage is empty.

Can anyone help me understand why I cant release either of these Refs without losing the final image?

Shouldn't they have been used up and done with by the time I return the grayBitmapImage created by the bytes[] buffer?

Does anyone see where else this function could cause memory leaks?

```
+ (NSData*) convertJpegToBmpGray: (UIImage *)houghSourceImage :(NSString *)destImgPath :(NSString *)fileName  :(int)width : (int)height
{
    RGBQUAD Palette[0x100];
    
    int totalbytesinbitmap = (int)(width * height) + 54 + (0x100 * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + 2);  //THE SIZE OF THE IMAGE WE WANT WITH NULL TERM
    
    //OUTPUT IMAGE BUFFER
    unsigned char *bytes = new unsigned char[totalbytesinbitmap];
    
    [self writeBitmapHeaderGray:bytes :width :height];
    
    UIImage *sourceImage1 = houghSourceImage;
    if(sourceImage1==nil)
        return nil;
    
    CGImageRef sourceImage = sourceImage1.CGImage;
    CFDataRef theData;
    theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage));
    
    UInt8 *pixelDataS = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theData);
    int dataLength = (int)CFDataGetLength(theData);  //LENGTH OF THE WHOLE BITMAP BUFFER
    
    int row = (int)height -1;                        //NUMBER OF ROWS IS THE HEIGHT MINUS 1
    
    int col = 0;

    int totalbytesinrow = (int) width;
    
    for(int i=0; i<dataLength;){
        
        int red     =   pixelDataS[i++];    //GET RED PIXEL
        int green   =   pixelDataS[i++];    //GET GREEN PIXEL
        int blue    =   pixelDataS[i++];    //GET BLUE PIXEL
                            i++;            //ADD A BYTE FOR RESERVED
        
        if(col == totalbytesinrow){
            col = 0;                       //RESET COLUMN COUNT TO ZERO AT END OF ROW
            row--;                         //FIGURE OUT THE ROW AND COLUMN COUNTS
        }
        
        //STARTS THE LOCATION FROM THE END OF THE BUFFER AND WORKS BACKWARDS IN ROWS
        int location = (row * totalbytesinrow) + col + 54 + (0x100 * sizeof(RGBQUAD));
        
                                            //CONVERT ALL PIXELS TO GRAY
        int gray = (red + green + blue) / 3;
        
        bytes[location]   = gray;
        col++;
         
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<0x100; i++)              //CREATE THE PALETTE ARRAY FOR USE WITH GREYSCALE BITMAPS
    {
        Palette[i].rgbRed = i;
        Palette[i].rgbGreen = i;
        Palette[i].rgbBlue = i;
        Palette[i].rgbReserved = 0;
    }
    
    int paletteLocation = 54;               //START THE PALETTE RIGHT AFTER THE INFOHEADER
    for(int i=0; i < 0x100; i++)            //COPY THE PALETTE ARRAY INTO THE BYTE ARRAY AFTER INFOHEADER
    {
        bytes[paletteLocation] = Palette[i].rgbRed;
        paletteLocation++;
        bytes[paletteLocation] = Palette[i].rgbGreen;
        paletteLocation++;
        bytes[paletteLocation] = Palette[i].rgbBlue;
        paletteLocation++;
        bytes[paletteLocation] = Palette[i].rgbReserved;
        paletteLocation++;
        
    }
    
    //ADD NULL TERMINATORS TO BITMAP BUFFER
    bytes[totalbytesinbitmap+1] = 0x00;
    bytes[totalbytesinbitmap+2] = 0x00;

    NSData *grayBitmapImage = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:totalbytesinbitmap];
    

    CFAutorelease(theData);  //EDIT-MEMORY LEAK FIXED BY ADDING THIS
    delete[] bytes;
    return grayBitmapImage;

}
```

The function is called like this.

```
UIImage *image = [ImageUtils UIImageFromCVMat:small];
int width = image.size.width;
int height = image.size.height;

NSData *raw2dmiImage = [ImageUtils convertJpegToBmpGray :image :savedFilePath :@"raw2dmiImage.BMP" :width :height];
```

Comment: It's `theData`. You got it by saying `CGDataProviderCopyData`. Did you read the docs? Did you see the word Copy? You must release that object. If the result that you are handing back involves that buffer's contents, then release it with `CFAutorelease`.

Comment: By the way, did you run the static analyzer? It should have told you that.

Comment: The static analyzer doesn't warn about the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). It _will,_ though, report a different, unrelated, problem in the code, namely he has a path of execution where if `sourceImage1` is `nil`, he's returning without ever deleting his `bytes`. But the failure to `CFRelease` the `theData` is the key problem.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but averaging red, green, and blue will not often yield a very good gray scale image. Usually you'd do use a [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) calculation, such as 0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the feedback, the average of the 3 colors is more than enough quality for the image recognition code that is receiving the image.  Thanks also for the other options with CFRelease, I'll give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: @Matt Thanks very much for your help, adding CFAutorelease(theData);  at the end cleaned it up and the image is still passed on which is great!   Appreciate it.